# No implicit conversion of nil into String on MessageVerifier

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Recently I received new project (backend of iOS app, actually) that works on Ruby (Rails).

I have a part of code in model (user):

```
155:  def self.create_access_token(user)
156:    verifier.generate(user.id)
157:  end
```

After some action that indirectly uses that part of code, in "Passenger" output I see following error that terminates everything:

```
TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):
  app/models/user.rb:156:in `create_access_token'
  app/models/user.rb:139:in `access_token'
  app/controllers/mailing_controller.rb:68:in `send_charts'
```

`verifier` is an instance of `ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier`

I'm totally sure that `user.id` contains valid value (I've tested it with `$stderr.puts`)

I'm completely new to this language, it's hard for me to figure out why this error appears. Hope someone can help.

Thanks!

Comment: I have a doubt on this assumption : "I'm totally sure that user.id contains valid value (I've tested it with $stderr.puts)". Just to be sure, could you write "puts user" in your function (before verifier.generate(user.id)) and tell me the answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it may the case user_id is nil. Anyway please check out [rubyonrails api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/MessageVerifier.html#method-i-generate) and verify generate method.

We can actually dig inside generate method. Use pry-rails gem for easy debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you did not set the `access_token_secret` in `secrets.yml`.